# In angular2 is it possible to add a variable to a route e.g. auth: true

Tags: angular

In angular2 is it possible to add a variable to a route e.g. auth: true

I want to do this so that on route change  in the app file I can then redirect them to homepage it they are not authenticated.

I have no code for this to show as I have no idea if this is possible.

code attempt:

```
      {
        path: 'myProfile',
        component: profileComponent,
        canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
      }
```

For the CanActivateTeam I need to pass in true or false.

So for a route e.g. myProfile I want it to have 2 variables e.g. isAuth: true or false, and another called isCompany: true or false. Everytime the route changes these need to be checked before component  loads. Therefore, I'd like this code in the app component globally

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: To be more specific , you need to implement CanActivate  guard

Comment: @JBNizet do you have a coding example of how this works for a speific route eg myProfile

Comment: @AngularM the page I linked to has a complete example, full of explanations and code.

Comment: @JBNizet I've had a look and updated my question a little

Comment: @JBNizet so for a route e.g. myProfile I want it to have 2 variables e.g. isAuth: true or false, and another called isCompany: true or false. Everytime the route changes these need to be checked before component  loads. Therefore, I'd like this code in the app component globally

Comment: Well, I would change your strategy, and instead of adding 2 boolean properties, add the AuthGuard if the user must be authenticated (and don't it it doesn't have to), and same for the other Guards. You could also add those two properties to the data of the route, and check them in the guard, but I don't see the point.

Comment: @JBNizet can you show me an example of data on the route? Reason being, I have views that companies can only see and views that general users can only see

Comment: You still haven't explained why you would just set the guard on routes that must be guarded, and not set it on the routes that must not be guarded. And regarding data, why don't you try something by yourself, by reading the documentation, first? The page I linked to explains how to pass data to routes. Take a step back, and read the whole guide on the router.

Comment: Some routes need user to be logged in and some dont. some routes are for companies only and some for general public and some for login in users only. I need a route to have these variables: doesRouteRequireAuth: true, isThisACompanyView: true for example

Comment: @AngularM. No. You need some routes to have `canActivate: [AuthGuard]`, because the user needs to be authenticated, and you need some routes to not have this guard, because anyone can activate the route.

Comment: Ok I see. Can this be a global module?

Comment: Also I need to know if the route is for companies. So the route needs a tag also. How would I do that

Comment: By creating another guard, and adding it to the array of guards when needed. Again, read the guide.